# Why is android ndk not compiling for multiple platforms?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I was trying out the ndk and a helloJNI project was compiled and run successfully. However I decided to go a little further and compile for other cpus. It was my understanding that I had to add a line

```
APP_ABI         :=all
```

to android.mk to build for multiple platforms. The full android.mk is as follows -

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := HelloJNI
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := HelloJNI.cpp
APP_ABI         :=all

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But the compiler is only compiling for arm. Please tell me if I am missing something here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `APP_ABI` line belongs in `Application.mk`, not `android.mk`, AFAIK.